# Unable to login in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4

i have created a messaging application. Main page contains two forms. One for registration and one for login. Both forms have different corresponding routes for processing. . On localhost, everything is working fine. Users are able to register and then login.

Today i uploaded files on the web server. Now it started showing token mismatch error. I searched a lot, but was unable to solve this.

Here is the View(named as login.blade.php) that has two forms

```
<div id="header">
    <center>
    <div id='loginform'>        
        {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login')) }}
            <div id='login_inputs_div'>
                {{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), array('placeholder'=>'Email', 'class'=>'inputs')) }}

                {{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder'=>'Password', 'class'=>'inputs')) }}

                {{ Form::submit('Log In', array('class'=>'submit')) }}
            </div>
            <div id='error_wrapper'>
                <div id='email_error'>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</div>
                <div id='password_error'>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</div>
                <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
    </center>
</div>


<div id="body">
    <div id='registration_alert_div'>
        <center>                                
            @if(Session::has('registration'))
                <div id="registration_alert">   
                    {{ Session::get('registration') }}
                </div>
            @endif              
        </center>
    </div>

    <div id="regform">
        {{  Form::open(array('url' => 'login/register')) }}
            <center><h1>Register To Make Friends</h1></center>
            {{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), array('id'=>'name', 'placeholder'=>'Name', 'class'=>'reginputs')) }}
            <span>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>

            {{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username'), array('id'=>'username', 'placeholder'=>'Username', 'class'=>'reginputs'))  }}
            <span>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</span>

            {{ Form::password('Password', array('id'=>'password', 'placeholder'=>'Password', 'class'=>'reginputs')) }}
            <span>{{ $errors->first('Password') }}</span>

            {{ Form::text('Email', Input::old('Email'), array('id'=>'email', 'placeholder'=>'Email', 'class'=>'reginputs')) }}
            <span>{{ $errors->first('Email') }}</span>

            {{ Form::text('ConfirmEmail', Input::old('ConfirmEmail'), array('id'=>'cemail', 'placeholder'=>'Confirm Your Email', 'class'=>'reginputs')) }}
            <span>{{ $errors->first('ConfirmEmail') }}</span>

            <center>{{ Form::submit('Register', array('class'=>'submit', 'id'=>'rsubmit')) }}</center>
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

Here are their respective routes:

```
//Route for forms display| showLogin method displays the view(login.route.php)
Route::get('login', array('uses' => 'HomeController@showLogin'));

//Route for processing login form
Route::post('login', array('before'=>'csrf', 'uses' => 'HomeController@doLogin'));

//route for processing registration form
Route::post('login/register', array('before'=> 'csrf', 'uses' => 'HomeController@register'));
```

I checked the source code and the token was present as an input field with some value. Why is it mismatching?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is probably not being able to keep a session in your webserver and everytime it starts a new session it creates a new token, which leads to the last one mismatch the current one. Some possible solutions:

1) Check if your webserver can write in `app/storage`, not only `app/storage/session`, because you might have problems with other files in that folder.

2) Change the session driver, for instance, from file to database (you will have to create the sessions table).